# Account recovery bug, always resets wrong account

Tags: support, accounts

I have for some unknown reason two logins attached to my account.  I want to reset the password for one specific account but even though I enter *that* account email address as the one to recover when I get the email with the reset link it always defaults to the other account name which I do not want to change.

Comment: That's unclear... You have two logins for one account, but specifying a login returns the wrong account... Which is it? One account two logins or one login two accounts?

Comment: You'll need to contact us (via the link in the footer) and provide the email address, as we cannot help you any without knowing what exactly you're typing into the box, or what profile you're trying to recover.

Comment: I have two email accounts associated with my stack overflow account.  I can login with an old email address which is no longer active as my credentials.  I also have a new email address which is associated with my stack overflow account and I do not have the password for that.  I go to stack overflow, enter the email address I do not have the pw for in the recovery box but it always sends me a reset for the account that I *do* have the login for and not the one I typed into the reset box.  Not sure how clearer I can make that.  It's clearly a serious bug.

Answer (score 1):

We do our best to look up the right account, starting with matching the email on the site you're using the recovery form on, then checking login credentials, etc. (Incidentally, being able to use multiple login credentials for a single account is a feature. I have something like six credentials I can and do use depending on which device I'm on. That isn't necessarily the problem here.)

It's possible that you have multiple accounts that share some combination of the fields we look at but in a way that wouldn't trigger a user merge. Sometimes it's edge cases all the way down. ;)

As animuson said in the comments, contact us with the specifics of what you're typing in and what account you're trying to recover. We'll be able to investigate at that point.

---

**Update**: after looking at the account, it does appear to be a bug in account recovery. The account has two email credentials, but only one StackId credential (read: only one of those emails has a password associated with it). When recovery is requested for the password-less email, we appear to be correctly finding the right SO account, but incorrectly "recovering" the wrong StackId. I'll dig more next week and update this post with either more details or confirmation of a fix, depending on how the digging goes.

Comment: I'll contact but fundamentally in what use case does it make sense to send a recovery link to a different email address than the one typed into the recovery box request in the first place?  Seems like a pretty straightforward fundamental bug as it should clearly *never* happen no matter the circumstances.

Comment: @JohnC Oh, it's sending to a completely different address? That's weird. "Shouldn't be happening" kind of weird. Still, need to look at the accounts to even diagnose what happened here.